# VB.NET Form Icon Error

Tags: vb.net, icons

Everytime I set the form icon, I get the following error :

*Value of type 'System.Drawing.Icon' cannot be converted to 'String'*

I have tried both external icon file and resources method, but none worked.

```
Dim X as new System.Drawing.Icon("icon.ico")
Me.Icon = X
```

and

```
Me.Icon = My.Resources.Icon
```

Same thing if I create a new project.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you added your own member named "Icon" to your form class, a property or field of type String.  Don't do that, pick another name.  The workaround (and proper code) is `MyBase.Icon = ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a WinForms application, your first attempt should work:

```
Me.Icon = New System.Drawing.Icon("path/to/.ico/file")
```

If you are writing your UI with WPF, then the .Icon property expects an ImageSource object:

```
Dim iconUri As New Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFIcon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
Me.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri)
```

The second example is directly taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).